# loading jQuery Thumbnail Scroller vertically and linking display content

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

am faily new to html.i want to create a three column html page.

colomn 1 - menu - vertical left.
column 2 - thumbnail - for each menu clicked it loads diff set of thumnail vertically.
column 3 - display area - for each thumnail click it should load diff content.

any suggestion??  example or reference appreciated.

thanks in advance.